# LocationManager not updating with filter

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have a LocationManager we use to log an iPads location for a business, and for some reason it will trigger it randomly even though I have it set up (I believe) correctly. Location Background is on. I am using Parse and Parse Server to saveEventually but either its not logging it or its not saving. I even went as far as to make silent audio keep the app fully alive in the background and its doing it, somewhat. Here is the code I am using, am I missing something?

```
    locationManager.delegate = self
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .NotDetermined:
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    case .AuthorizedAlways:
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    default:
        break
    }
```

and

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.last {

        let loc = LocationTracker()
        loc.timeStamp = location.timestamp
        loc.device = UIDevice.currentDevice().name
        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
            loc.user = PFUser.currentUser()
        }
        loc.location = PFGeoPoint(location: location)
        loc.saveEventually()
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt recognize what your problem is..
if your problem is 
the location manager updates everytime, then you need to use: locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() in 
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])

Comment: My issue is that it is NOT updating every 100meters like it should be. It's doing it randomly and I'm not sure why it's not every 100 meters.

Comment: Just run the code in simulator set in city ride and you will see it working..For me its updating every 500m not on every 100m in device